# Type compatibility in languages

Tags: java, c++, c, types, type-conversion

What type in Java corresponds to the long int type in C? It me interests in communication by creation of native of methods by means of JNI.

Comment: `long int` in C can be `int` or `long` type in Java, depending on OS and platform.

Comment: @nhahtdh I use solaris from Nexenta.

Comment: long int in C is a signed datatype, hence you can easily use it with long in Java. Had it been an unsigned datatype, you'd have to use the next higher datatype in Java, i.e. BigInteger.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the size of the `long` datatype as supported by your C / C++ compiler.  That depends on your hardware (32 bit versus 64 bit) and the compiler and compiler switches.  What we can say for sure is that Java `long` is 64-bit signed and Java `int` is 32-bit signed.

This SO post deals with the size of C / C++ data types - [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc) - and one of the Answers gives you a simple way to find the size of any given primitive type ... on *your* machine with *your* compiler and *your* compiler settings.

Comment: I use 64 bit Nexenta operating system.

Comment: For Nexenta: after read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexenta_OS, it looks int and long are 32 bits. To have 64 bits int you have to say "long long int". A more detailed response at http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html.

Comment: @Aubin - however, the OP would be advised to check using `cout << "sizeof datatype = " << sizeof(long int) << endl;`

Comment: Yes, but today, it's very rare to see sizeof( int ) = 8 or sizeof( long ) = 8 (as shown by references in previous comment)